# No overload matches this call. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Signals'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, signals

I am using typescript to build a microservice and handling signals as well. The code was working fine till a few days ago but recently it started throwing errors. Couldn't find a fix for the issue.

code for handling signals. It is just part of the file.
`src/main.ts`

```
  enum signals {
    SIGHUP = 1,
    SIGINT = 2,
    SIGTERM = 15
  }
  const shutdown = (signal, value) => {
    logger.warn("shutdown!")
    Db.closeAll()
    process.exit(value)
  }
  Object.values(signals).forEach(signal => {
    process.on(signal, () => {
      logger.warn(`process received a ${signal} signal`)
      shutdown(signal, signals[signal])
    })
  })
```

When I do `ts-node src/main.ts` The following error throws and exits.

```
/home/meraj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:245
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/main.ts:35:16 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | signals' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Signals'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Signals'.

35     process.on(signal, () => {
                  ~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/node/base.d.ts:653:9
    653         on(event: Signals, listener: SignalsListener): this;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The last overload is declared here.

    at createTSError (/home/meraj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:245:12)
    at reportTSError (/home/meraj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:249:19)
    at getOutput (/home/meraj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:362:34)
    at Object.compile (/home/meraj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:395:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/meraj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:473:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/meraj/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:476:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Any fix would be appreciated. Or If you can tell why it was working earlier just 2 days ago and not now.

Comment: Is `process.on()` expecting its first argument to be a number or a string?  According to the docs, it looks like it should be a string. `Object.values(signals)` returns an array of numbers.  I think you want `Object.keys(signals)`, and I'm guessing what changed in the last two days is you set the enum values to numbers rather than constant strings.

Comment: As long as I talk about enum which is not changed for quite a long time, And I thought maybe the number is creating a problem and converted it to string but still did not worked.

Comment: Try changing from `Object.values()` to `Object.keys()`

Answer (score 28):

This sometimes happens when you have passed an incorrect number of arguments to an anonymous function:

```
    Object.keys(data).reduce((key: string) => {

    }, {});
```

will raise error:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3

Pass it the correct number of arguments:

```
    Object.keys(data).reduce((acc: any, key: string) => {
    }, {});
```

Comment: I had the same message "No overload matches this call."  It was because I didn't pass the right number of params.

Answer (score 11):

I also had this strange issue, but I worked around it using type assertions (in my case using a string enum):

```js
(Object.values(someEnum) as string[]).concat(otherStringArray);
```

Comment: May you elaborate a bit how you solved it? Maybe you could also help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502778/ please?

Answer (score 8):

#### Solution 1: Keep [numeric enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums) `signals`

```
Object.values(signals)
  // numeric enum includes reverse mapping, filter numbers out and keep "SIGHUP" etc.
  .filter((s): s is NodeJS.Signals => typeof s !== "number") 
  .forEach(signal => {
    process.on(signal, ...) // works now
  })
```

#### Solution 2: Use pure signal string literal types

```
// these string literal items are strongly typed by built-in NodeJS.Signals type
Object.values<NodeJS.Signals>(["SIGHUP", "SIGINT", "SIGTERM"])
  .forEach(signal => {
    process.on(signal, ...) // works now
  })
```

#### Solution 3: Change to [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) (no reverse mapping)

```
enum signals2 {
  SIGHUP = "SIGHUP",
  SIGINT = "SIGINT",
  SIGTERM = "SIGTERM"
}

Object.values(signals2)
  .forEach(signal => {
    process.on(signal, ...) // works now
  })
```

#### Why does the error happen?

Numeric enums like `signals` include a [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-runtime). For example you can do the following:

```
const r1 = signals.SIGHUP // r1 value: 1
const r2 = signals[signals.SIGINT] // r2 value: "SIGINT"
const r3 = signals[15] // r3 value: "SIGTERM"
```

That is why you get `(string | signals)[]` back for `Object.values(signals)`, where `string` stands for the enum keys and `signals` for the enum values.

Now, parameter `signal` in [`process.on(signal, ...)`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/27123c0/types/node/globals.d.ts#L913) must be one of the [predefined Node.JS string literal types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/27123c0/types/node/globals.d.ts#L647-L651). However we pass in `string | signals` item type, so TS yells at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I got this kind of typescript error when I passed a non-async function to a method that expected an async function.

Answer (score 1):

In my case below will return `error TS2769: No overload matches this call.`

```
Object.values(poll.votes).reduce((sum: number, vote: string) => {
    return sum + vote.length;
  }, 0);
```

It happens because TypeScript isn't able to infer the type of `vote` correctly from `Object.values(poll.votes)`, resulting in the error. The solution is set `as string[]` to `Object.values(poll.votes)` like below:

```js
(Object.values(poll.votes) as string[]).reduce((sum: number, vote) => {
    return sum + vote.length;
  }, 0);
```

or another way just create a new variable for `Object.values(poll.votes)`:

```
  const votes: string[] = Object.values(poll.votes);
  const totalVotes: number = votes.reduce((sum: number, vote) => {
    return sum + vote.length;
  }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you do not assign your types properly.

Your variable data Type MUST match the passing data type.

```
organizationList: { id: string; name: string;  }[] = [] //if you do this way it type error
organizationList: Organization[] = [] //correct defining method 

get Org() {
    return this.list.filter((org: Organization) => org.id == this.id) //this data type must defined data type
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

A strange case that happened to me in regards to this kind of error could be for example

```
somePath = somePath.replace(/\//g, /\\\//g);
```

use instead

```
somePath= somePath.replace("/", "\/");
somePath= somePath.replace(/\//, "\/");
```

because the second argument in `replace` is of type string.