# How to repair a 'TS2769: No overload matches this call'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

After package updates, I suddenly get weird typescript errors:

> [tsl] ERROR in C:..\UI\src\sagas.ts(40,21)
>         **TS2769: No overload matches this call.**
>
> The last overload gave the following error.     Argument of type '"LOAD_IDS"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakeableChannel'.

The corresponding lines 39-41 of `sagas.ts` are

```js
function* watchIds() {
    yield takeEvery(Actions.LOAD_IDS, loadIds);
}
```

The function `function* loadIds({ forceReload })` is defined in the same `sagas.ts` and just the API call.

**What does the TS error mean and how do I fix it?**

1. My `packages.json` look like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/nJ0cPNXb
2. Maybe also important: My `webpack.config.js` is https://pastebin.com/raw/JNdXTCMb

#### References

- [No overload matches this call. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Signals'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722093/no-overload-matches-this-call-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-signals)
- https://engineering.datorama.com/demystifying-function-overloading-in-typescript-eb9f8ca6b87d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My colleague eventually taught me a workaround:

1. Exclude the corresponding action, e.g. `takeEvery` from the original `import` statement.
2. Import all action with `as Eff` where `Eff` is an alias.
3. Define a new constant with the same name as the original action.

```js
import { put, fork, select, call } from 'redux-saga/effects' // <-- modified
import * as Eff from 'redux-saga/effects'  // <-- new

// ... 

const takeEvery: any = Eff.takeEvery;      // <-- new
const takeLatest: any = Eff.takeLatest;    // <-- new
```

As far as I understand him, the idea is to explicity allow `any`  type.

**Edit:** I am aware that Facebook (as developer of React) does explicitly state that one should **not** use inheritance, see https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: Composition vs inheritance is for React components, not all code in the project.

Answer (score 5):

I also met this problem, but I asked my colleague and learned about the following solution:

redux-saga takes `TakeableChannel<unknown>`. This is an action, so you declare type of loadIds's argument is shape of action like this:

```js
function* loadIds({
   forceReload
}: { 
   type: string;
   forceReload: any; // your forceReload type
}) {
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for a solution about similar problem with yield call.

Don't like to put any... clean code that works for me:

```
yield call<typeof myFunction>(myFunction, {
    type: 'path',
    payload: {
        year: 2023
    }
})
```

note: if you don't know the type value, the corrector in visual studio tells you what it is expected. I believe it is the "slice name/reducer" from what I got

Answer (score -2):

I could fix such an issue by casting `variableThatRaisesIssue` twice:

```
variableThatRaisesIssue as unknown as any
```