# No overload matches this call in saga call effect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, saga

I want to pass action.url string as a parameter of topicDummy function which return Promise, 
but It keeps show me

```js
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '<TopicData>(url: string) => Promise<TopicData>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ context: unknown; fn: (this: unknown, ...args: any[]) => any; }'.
      Type '<TopicData>(url: string) => Promise<TopicData>' is missing the following properties from type '{ context: unknown; fn: (this: unknown, ...args: any[]) => any; }': context, fnts(2769)
effects.d.ts(499, 17): The last overload is declared here.
```

these are my whole codes.

```js
export type TopicData = {
  name: TopicName
  data: CardData[]
}
const dummyTopicData: TopicData = Object.assign({
  topic: 'etc',
  data: dummyData()
}, )
function topicDummy<TopicData>(url: string): Promise<TopicData> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => 
      dummyTopicData 
    , 700);  
  })   
}

function* fetchTopic(action: DispatchAction){
  try{
    yield put(topicCreator.load()); 
    const topicList = yield call(topicDummy, action.url); // <- complain here. 
    yield put(topicCreator.success(topicList));
  } catch(error){
    throw new Error(`Error exist in fetchTopic function`); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

[How to repair a 'TS2769: No overload matches this call'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58814026/128165) might be relevant,

It suggest that instead of

```
import {call} from "redux-saga/effects";
```

to use

```
import * as Effects from "redux-saga/effects";

const call: any = Effects.call;
```

Also have a look at https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/2018

---

You will also need to resolve the promise at one point, and you need to "*return*" the data if you want to use them.

So change

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => 
      dummyTopicData 
    , 700);  
  })
```

to

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => 
      resolve(dummyTopicData)
    , 700);  
  })
```

Comment: could yon explain why should I use  * as Effects and this makes work?

Comment: @jay1234 not really. I am not TS knowledgeable. I just searched a bit and pointed to some possible solutions according to my findings.

Comment: This is very bad solution to skip typing and use any.

Comment: @DanielKmak feel free to add a more complete answer. It could provide much value as this seems to not be an isolated case.  As i mentioned in a previous comment, this answer was just the result of some looking around.

Answer (score 8):

I think I had the same problem, and I found the solution in my case.

I had this code:

```
    const {dashboardId} = yield call(
      createProgramDashboard,
      programId,
      name,
      type
    );
```

I got a red squiggly line under `createProgramDashboard`, with this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(programId: string, name: string, type: REPORT_TYPE) => Promise<Dictionary>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ context: unknown; fn: (this: unknown, ...args: any[]) => any; }'.
      Type '(programId: string, name: string, type: REPORT_TYPE) => Promise<Dictionary<any>>' is missing the following properties from type '{ context: unknown; fn: (this: unknown, ...args: any[]) => any; }': context, fnts(2769)
effects.d.ts(499, 17): The last overload is declared here.
```

It turns out that the first parameter I was sending in, `programId`, was a `number`, while `createProgramDashboard` was expecting a `string`.

Apparently this error is displayed when the types of some of the arguments sent to the `call` function (in my case `programId: number`) don't match the types of the params expected (in my case `programId: string`) by the function being called, (in my case `createProgramDashboard`).

So this fixed the error:

```
    const {dashboardId} = yield call(
      createProgramDashboard,
      programId.toString(),
      name,
      type
    );
```

Comment: real answer and cleanest right here. might also be more subtle like expecting string | undefined instead of just string